# How to install NLTK on my webserver

Tags: python, nltk

Ok I edited my question since I now have a host that does support ssh.

**How can i install the nltk module for python using ssh?**

I tried contacting support but they can't seem to help me. You guys any ideas? How can I install modules in general on my webserver? what's the hosting's equivalent of sudo python setup.py install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need shell access (though not necessarily `root` access) to properly install a Python module.

However, since you're able to execute Python code on the remote, you might be able to set up a script that you can run through a web browser that runs [`python setup.py install --home=DIR`](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#alternate-installation-the-home-scheme) for NLTK on the remote, where `DIR` is a directory on your [`PYTHONPATH`](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) where you have write access. (This solution should be considered a crude hack, though.)

**EDIT**: forget the above, good that you have shell access. Make a dir `~/apps` (or similar), put that in the `PYTHONPATH` of the account used to run your Python web serving code (not necessarily your own, please check first) and install it in that dir using the [home scheme](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#alternate-installation-the-home-scheme).

Comment: so that's ssh right? I could also host it at alwaysdata where i do have ssh. However, how do I get to a command line interface with ssh? ( as you can see i've never used ssh)

Comment: `ssh username@remote.host` (or use Putty when on Windows)

Comment: Yes use Putty. It works very much like telnet but a bit more secure. if you host accepts neither, then it is probably time for a new web host...

Comment: ok I now use alwaysdata as host and managed to log in via ssh using terminal on mac. any clues on how to install nltk over there (i have ssh now)

Comment: `wget` it from the source, unpack, follow instructions in `README` and/or `INSTALL`.

Comment: ok instruction just mention python setup.py install. However changed my .bash_profile to: have this in it: export PYTHONPATH = ~ / cgi-bin /. Then i run python setup.py install (for pyyaml) but I get this error: running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running install_lib
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yaml
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yaml': Permission denied. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to install into `/usr/local`, a dir that belongs to the sysadmin. Read my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @larsmans' instructions, you probably will also need to download relevant data for your NLTK installation. To do that, run the following after you successfully install the module:

```
$ python
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download()
```

This function will then guide you through the process of downloading the corpora.

Comment: thanks for the info, i alrady did that once for my pc version, however i still am struggeling with the nltk install itself..